# Writing SQL queries with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, sql

I never really paid much attention on how I was writing my SQL queries with PyQGIS since I didn't encounter any issues so far.

However, I'm currently having difficulties building a SQL query based on values stored in a checkable combobox and I realize that I'm probably not building my SQL queries really well since I can't overcome my problem.

What I did:

code sample:

```
self.sql_layer1 = """SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE SUBSTR(id, 9, 2) IN ('""" + str(self.dlg.mComboBox.currentText()) + """')"""

self.uri.setDataSource("", self.sql_layer1, "geom", "", "gid")

self.layer1= QgsVectorLayer(self.uri.uri(), "layer1", "postgres")
if not self.layer1.isValid:
    print('Error !')
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.layer1 )
```

The problem is that my SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE SUBSTR(gid, 9, 2) IN ('5U, 7O, 8C')
```

But it should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE SUBSTR(gid, 9, 2) IN ('5U', '7O', '8C')
```

How should I write my SQL query?

Comment: Could you tell us what is the class of your "checkable combobox"?

Comment: This is less about writing SQL and more about formatting strings. You should certainly learn how to use `str.join()`.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo it's a QgsCheckableComboBox

Comment: @Vince may I ask you where I could find a simple example of the use of str.join() with pyqgis and sql ? 

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/q/10880813/13787804 but it's not crystal clear !

Comment: Right, @Vince. Just wanted to know if the `QgsCheckableComboBox` had a handy method to format checked items (apparently not as @Linda needs it), before closing the question. @Linda, given your string `self.dlg.mComboBox.currentText()` (let's call it `s`), you could use, e.g., `str(tuple(s.split(", ")))`.

Comment: It's working ! Thanks German, if you publish your comment as the answer I could validate it

Comment: @Linda, let's follow the rules and proceed to close the question because it has no GIS component involved. Next time please ask directly in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Assuming appropriately initialized variables, with the selected text as a list,  `sql = "SELECT * FROM {:s} WHERE SUBSTR(gid, 9, 2) IN ('{:s}')".format(tablename,"','".join(selected_text))`

Answer (score 0):

First off, never use string concatenation when you're building SQL query strings. It's a bad habit, as it'll leave you vulnerable to SQL injections if you ever give people access to your code, say, via a website.

In your example, you're constructing a list from a ComboBox to populate an IN clause. You'd want to create a variable that concatenates those inputs together.

IF you do this in PostgreSQL, [then you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355567/query-in-clause-with-parameter):

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE SUBSTR(gid, 9, 2) IN (SELECT UNNEST(string_to_array($myvariable, ',')));
```

There are ways to generate the clause in Python as well, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Encomium. I tried this: self.sql_layer1 = "SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE SUBSTR(gid, 9, 2) IN (SELECT UNNEST(string_to_array($self.dlg.mComboBox.currentText(), ',' )))" but unfortunately it didn't work... I shall later read the link you provide in your answer I guess